# I am trying to extract data from a website in python

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, python-newspaper

```
def convert():
    for url in url_list:
        news=Article(url)
        news.download()
        while news.download_state != 2:
            time.sleep(1)
        news.parse()
        l.append(
            {'Title':news.title, 'Text': news.text.replace('\n',' '), 'Date':news.publish_date, 'Author':news.authors}
        )

convert()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(l)
df.to_csv('Amazon_try2'+'.csv',encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

The function convert() goes through a list of url and process each of them. Each url is a link to an article. I am fetching the important attributes of articles such as author, text etc and then storing this in a data frame. After that, I am converting data frame to a csv file. The script ran for about 5 hours as there were 589 urls in url_list. But I still couldn't get the csv file. Can somebody spot out where I am going wrong.

Comment: What do you mean "I still couldn't get the csv file" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably your function stops here:

```
    while news.download_state != 2:
        time.sleep(1)
```

it is waiting for the change of the download state but it never happens. your function should also return a list

something like this should work:

```
def convert():
    for url in url_list:
        news=Article(url)
        news.download()

        news.parse()
        l.append(
            {'Title':news.title, 'Text': news.text.replace('\n',' '), 'Date':news.publish_date, 'Author':news.authors}
        )
    return l 

l = convert()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(l)
df.to_csv('Amazon_try2'+'.csv',encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Comment: The problem is that if I dont put the sleep function then some exception occurs which says that an article should be downloaded without parsing and the code stops. Can you suggest a way of dealing with this method

Comment: then you can use a timeout, if it doesn't change within 30 seconds just drop it and move on. There's definitely a @timeout decorator somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your whole program, you need to return l from convert.

```
def convert():
    for url in url_list:
        news=Article(url)
        news.download()
        while news.download_state != 2:
            time.sleep(1)
        news.parse()
        l.append(
            {'Title':news.title, 'Text': news.text.replace('\n',' '), 'Date':news.publish_date, 'Author':news.authors}
        )
    return l 

l = convert()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(l)
df.to_csv('Amazon_try2'+'.csv',encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but I had declared l is global here so that's not the case here. But okay I should return l

Comment: It doesn't say global inside convert() - if you put 'global' in the module scope it doesn't do anything, has to be inside the function.

    test = 123
    global test

    def f0():
        test = 234

    >>> test
    123
    >>> f0()
    >>> test
    123

Comment: Actually I am working in jupyter notebook so I have declared all the variables in one cell so that's the case